# Hard Code Image into class file

Tags: java, image, filesize, hardcode

I have in the past downloaded a tool that will take an image file as input and output a source file extending the `Image` class that can be used for graphics. I now have a practical application for this tool, but I no longer have a copy. I have searched many times in hope of finding it again without luck.

I would like to know how to hard code an image inside a class (no external image loading). I would actually use a `char[]` to store all the bytes, but arrays have have a length size limit that images often exceed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you really need to store the image inside a class? Loading the image from a resource stored in a JAR file seems the most natural method to me. It doesn't store the image in the class but if you build your app to a JAR or WAR file, no external files are needed. The upside is that the image can be stored as-is in your sources dir, so you can e.g. edit it with a regular image editor, which you can't if it's encoded inside a class.

Answer (score 0):

You could base64 encode the data.

Apache commons codec provides a base64 encoder and decoder. Then you could use an [online tool](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) to encode your image into base64. Just write a literal string in your java file that contains the text output by the encoder.

To access the image, first decode the Base64 string into a byte array.

Then you can create your image:
`ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(base64bytes))`

Your length size limit is also essentially irrelevant because the size limit of a java array is the integer type, which goes up above 2 billion, or 2 gigabytes.

Comment: oh yeah, I thought that `length` was a short... I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way would be just storing the image bytes as a `String` inside a class. This way is used, for example, by LWJGL in [`LWJGLUtil` class](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/master/src/java/org/lwjgl/LWJGLUtil.java#L62). They convert the string to a [`ByteBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) using the following function:

```
private static ByteBuffer loadIcon(String data) {
    int len = data.length();
    ByteBuffer bb = BufferUtils.createByteBuffer(len);
    for(int i=0 ; i<len ; i++) {
        bb.put(i, (byte)data.charAt(i));
    }
    return bb.asReadOnlyBuffer();
}
```

Where [`BufferUtils.createByteBuffer`](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/master/src/java/org/lwjgl/BufferUtils.java#L59) is declared as

```
public static ByteBuffer createByteBuffer(int size) {
    return ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(size).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
}
```